# How can i insert javascript variable in value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

this is the value in my input field

```
value="CODES-{{ date("Ym_M") }}-PRJ-PONUMBER-SHORTTEXT"
```

i have this variable in javascript

```
var codes = PC123; this is dynamic
var ponumber = 4124;this is dynamic
var shorttext = 001; this is dynamic
```

I want a result of:

```
//PC123-202105_May-PRJ-4124-001
```

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: that value is from HTML input field.

Comment: Are you wanting it where there are three input boxes (codes, ponnumber, and shorttext) and it results in that output string, or are you wanting to take in a single long string and pull out codes, ponnumber, and shorttext from that and store those as variables?

Comment: Please only use tags relevant to what you are asking next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the date in a data-* attribute and then use javascript to set the input.

```xml
<input id="myInput" type="text" data-date="{{ date('Ym_M') }}">
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myInput'); // or $('#myInput'); in JQuery
var codes = 'PC123';
var date = input.dataset.date; // or $('#myInput').data('date'); in JQuery
var ponumber = '4124';
var shorttext = '001';

input.value = `${codes}-${date}-PRJ-${ponumber}-${shorttext}`; // or $('#myInput').val(`${codes} .... `); in JQuery
```